# Как менять дизайн веб приложения, написанного на java?

Tags: java

С помощью чего можно изменять дизайн веб приложения написанного на java?

Например дизайн кнопки поменять и т .д.

Answer (score 1):

с помощью css. что такое [css](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Каскадные_таблицы_стилей)

учебник по css [тут](http://ru.html.net/tutorials/css/)